# c# compare datetime for day of month and time

Tags: c#

I need to compare two datetime variable only for some criteria :
Day of the month and time .

If the day of the month and the time is equal to another datetime then the expression return true, the comparison must not keep in mind of the month and the year of the two Datetime .

What's the best way to do this comparison ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why people just downvote without commenting. -1 for person who did downvote this question without proper explanation.

Comment: @Miguel: +1; IMO it is a crime..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare the [Day](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.day.aspx) and the [TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) properties of the two [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values:

```
bool areEqual = (d1.Day == d2.Day)
             && (Math.Abs((d1.TimeOfDay - d2.TimeOfDay).TotalSeconds) < 1.0);
```

Adjust for different time zones before comparing if necessary.

Comment: or follow best practise and convert everything back to UTC first, then compare second.

Comment: Yes, but i need to compare the time not considering milliseconds for example now i compare only the time with this expression : (Math.Abs((d1 - d2).TotalSeconds) < 1)